# how do I display a 2 dimensional datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'd like to design an interface showing buttons in a data grid - for each day and its 24 hours. All in all we'll be showing: 24 * 7 = 168 buttons.

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Create 24 columns (of DGVButtons) then add 7 rows, or contrary.

Answer (score 1):

I did an example code of how it ca ne done!
This code only creates the buttons, so check it out:
note: name buttons your own way, I only did an example!

```
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewButtonColumn btnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btnColumn.HeaderText = string.Format("{0}:00", i+1);
            btnColumn.Name = "dayColumn";
            btnColumn.Width = 40; //set yout width
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btnColumn);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                dataGridView1[j, i].Value = string.Format("{0}:00", (j + 1));
            }
        }
```

--

Maybe subscribing to an event handler, when some button is clicked is a good idea:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewButtonColumn btnColumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            btnColumn.HeaderText = string.Format("{0}:00", i+1);
            btnColumn.Name = "dayColumn";
            btnColumn.Width = 40; //set yout width
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(btnColumn);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString();
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
                dataGridView1[j, i].Value = string.Format("{0}:00", (j + 1));
        }
        dataGridView1.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellClick);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string day = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value.ToString();
        string hour = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("you have clciked on day: " + day + ", hour: " + hour);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a framework interface called `ITypedList` which allows you to directly specify properties to be displayed for each constituent member, in a way that databinding understands.

Realise that attempting to do binding in this way is **absolutely hideous**. The basic steps are as follows:

- Implement a collection type that implements `ITypedList`;
- For each item in the collection, return a `PropertyDescriptor` which encapsulates the value of the row/column pair;
- Databind to the collection as normal

I've done this as an experiment and it works, but the hoops you'll have to jump through to get everything to work properly are a nightmare. Still, I'd usually consider it better than manipulating view logic directly. DataGridView is meant to be intelligent enough to infer everything it needs to do from binding, and if I can modify the binding target rather than the control, that's what I'd prefer.